# SPO How to Change the Hoverpanel in Item Display Template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template

I am using Scot Hillier's excellent example of a grid display control/item display template set for search results on Sharepoint Online.

I need to employ a copy of the OOTB Hoverpanel for PDF Items instead of the embedded one in his example. I altered the hoverURL assignment as shown below:

```
                var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_SEDA_HoverPanel.js";
```

I altered the div tag onmouseover and onmouseout actions to call showHoverPanelCallback rather than the document.getElementByID call that displays the embedded hoverpanel detailed on the item display template.

**EDIT: I added the changes described by @Aveenav below**

I Changed:

```
<div style="min-width:150px;width:150px;max-width:150px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="javascript:document.getElementById('_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_').style.display = 'none';">
```

To This:

```
<div  id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" class="use-class-name-here" data-displaytemplate="SEDAItem" style="min-width:150px;width:150px;max-width:150px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;" onmouseover="_#=showHoverPanelCallback=#_" onmouseout="_#=hideHoverPanelCallback=#_">
```

There must be a secret to this that I am unaware of... Any ideas?

**EDIT: Item Template Code Added**

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>SEDA Table Item</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the default result item template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">
'Title':'Title',
'Path':'Path',
'Description':'Description',
'EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER',
'LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime',
'CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus',
'DocId':'DocId',
'HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary',
'HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties',
'FileExtension':'FileExtension',
'ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime',
'ParentLink':'ParentLink',
'FileType':'FileType',
'IsContainer':'IsContainer',
'SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension',
'DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor',
'Filename':'Filename',
'TcIDOWSTEXT':'TcIDOWSTEXT',
'RevOWSTEXT':'RevOWSTEXT',
'ImageOWSBOOL':'ImageOWSBOOL',
'ParentImageOWSTEXT':'ParentImageOWSTEXT',
'LastModDateOWSDATE':'LastModDateOWSDATE',
'ECIDOWSTEXT':'ECIDOWSTEXT',
'ECStatusOWSCHCS':'ECStatusOWSCHCS'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://MySite.sharepoint.com/sites/SEDASEARCHTEST/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Table_SEDADefault.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="Table_Default">
    <!--#_
            if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
                var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
                var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
                var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_PDF_HoverPanel.js";
                $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
                var k = ctx.DataProvider.get_currentQueryState().k;
                if(!Srch.U.e(k)){
                    ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path = ctx.CurrentItem.Path + "#search=" + $urlKeyValueEncode(k);
                }
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getIconUrlByFileExtension(ctx.CurrentItem);
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenControl = "PdfFile.OpenDocuments";

                //Show Hover
                var showHoverPanelCallback = ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback;
                if (Srch.U.n(showHoverPanelCallback)) {
                    showHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
                }

                //Hide Hover
                var hideHoverPanelCallback = ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback;
                if (Srch.U.n(hideHoverPanelCallback)) {
                    hideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
                }

                //ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
                //ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();

                getBackgroundColor = function () {
                  var idParts = itemId.split('_');
                  if((idParts[idParts.length-2].match(/[0-9]+/) % 2) === 0){
                    return '#fff';
                  }
                  else {
                    return '#eee';
                  }
                };


                formatProperties = function (inString) {
                  try {
                    var divString = "<div style='display:list-item;list-style-type:disc;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;'>";
                    var outString = inString;
                    outString =  outString.replace('</HHTitle>','</div>');
                    outString =  outString.replace('<HHTitle>', divString);
                    outString =  outString.replace('</HHUrl>','</div>');
                    outString =  outString.replace('<HHUrl>', divString);
                    outString =  outString.replace('</c0>','</strong>');
                    outString =  outString.replace('<c0>','<strong>');
                    return outString;
                  }
                  catch(err) {
                    return "";
                  }
                };

                formatDelimiters = function (inString) {
                  try {
                    if (inString.indexOf(';') > -1)
                    { 
                        inString = inString.replace(/;/g,'<br/>'); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inString = inString.replace(', ','<br/>');
                        inString = inString.replace(', ','<br/>');
                        inString = inString.replace(', ','<br/>');
                    }

                    return inString
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                    return "";
                  }
                }

               formatDate = function (inDate) {
                  try {
                    var newDate = new Date(inDate.substring(0,19));
                    return newDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')

                  }
                  catch (err) {
                    return "";
                  }
                };

              formatAccountName = function (inString) {
                  try {
                    var parts = inString.split('|');
                    if(parts.length===2){
                      return parts[0];
                    }
                    else {
                      return parts[1];
                    }
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                    return "";
                  }
              };
    _#-->
    <div style="display:table;width:840px;">
        <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" class="ms-srch-item" data-displaytemplate="PDFItem" style="display: table-row;background-color: _#=getBackgroundColor()=#_;" onmouseover="_#=showHoverPanelCallback=#_" onmouseout="_#=hideHoverPanelCallback=#_">
            <div   style="min-width:150px;width:150px;max-width:150px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;"> 
             <!-- <div style="min-width:150px;width:150px;max-width:150px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="javascript:document.getElementById('_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_').style.display = 'none';"> -->
    <!--#_
            var name = ctx.CurrentItem.Filename.substring(0,12)
            if (ctx.CurrentItem.ImageOWSBOOL.indexOf("True") != -1)
            {
    _#-->
                <a href="_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Path=#_" target="_blank"><strong>_#=name=#_</strong></a>
    <!--#_
            } else {
    _#-->  
                _#=name=#_
    <!--#_
            }
    _#--> 
            </div>
            <div style="min-width:40px;width:40px;max-width:40px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                _#=formatProperties(ctx.CurrentItem.RevOWSTEXT)=#_
            </div>
            <div style="min-width:200px;width:200px;max-width:200px;display: table-cell;white-space:wrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                _#=formatDelimiters(ctx.CurrentItem.Title)=#_
            </div>
            <div style="min-width:100px;width:100px;max-width:100px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">

                _#=formatDate(ctx.CurrentItem.LastModDateOWSDATE)=#_
            </div>
            <div style="min-width:150px;width:150px;max-width:150px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
               <a href="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/SEDASEARCHTEST/Pages/results.aspx#k=_#=ctx.CurrentItem.ParentImageOWSTEXT=#_" target="_blank"> _#=formatProperties(ctx.CurrentItem.ParentImageOWSTEXT)=#_ </a>
            </div>                
            <div style="min-width:80px;width:80px;max-width:80px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
               <a href="https://mysite/sites/forms/ecr/_#=ctx.CurrentItem.ECIDOWSTEXT=#_.xml" target="_blank"> _#=ctx.CurrentItem.ECIDOWSTEXT=#_ </a>
            </div>                
            <div style="min-width:100px;width:100px;max-width:100px;display: table-cell;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                _#=formatProperties(ctx.CurrentItem.ECStatusOWSCHCS)=#_
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
 <!-- 
    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" style="display:none;padding:15px;width:1050px;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff;box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #888;border:1px #000 solid;padding:10px;">
            <div style="font-weight:bold"> 
                 _#=ctx.CurrentItem.Title=#_
            </div>
            <div>
                 _#=STSHtmlDecode(ctx.CurrentItem.HitHighlightedSummary)=#_
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
-->        
    <!--#_
            }
    _#-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it be ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback and not ctx.CurrentItem.csr_HideHoverPanelCallback?

Compare your code with the following snippet: and use the function names (showHoverPanelCallback & hideHoverPanelCallback) on the mouseover and mouseout events.

```
    var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
    var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
    var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
    var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_SEDA_HoverPanel.js";
    $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem); //needed

    //Show Hover
    var showHoverPanelCallback = ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback;
    if (Srch.U.n(showHoverPanelCallback)) {
        showHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
    }

    //Hide Hover
    var hideHoverPanelCallback = ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback;
    if (Srch.U.n(hideHoverPanelCallback)) {
        hideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
    }
```

Make sure your html content is similar to the snippet below (the second div is needed)

```
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" class="use-class-name-here" data-displaytemplate="SEDAItem" onmouseover="_#= showHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= hideHoverPanelCallback =#_">

            </div>
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thx @Aveenav, you're right about the typo changes, but I still can't get the hoverpanel to display. I added the Show Hover and Hide Hover snippets from your post and replaced onmouseover="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_"  with onmouseover="_#=ShowHoverPanelCallback=#_". Is this the solution you were describing?

Comment: #=ShowHoverPanelCallback=# or #=showHoverPanelCallback=# ?

Comment: the editor is stripping out the underbars, but they're in there...

Comment: i meant, did you check the case show... vs Show...? See console for errors and attach the debugger wit breakpoints.

Comment: Thx again @Aveenav, case matters, and I had it wrong... still no hoverpanel though... I am seeing several entries in the console like this:
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/forbidframing.htm
It appears there's a violation of the https standards in thee somewhere?

Comment: those warnings are not related to the issue. see the updated answer.

Comment: That's got it @Aveenav! The div updates were the trick... Thx for your patience!

Comment: So the hover panels are displaying properly (Thx @Aveenav!) but the image of the PDF file housed in the document library is not displaying :(
I'm using direct copies of the Item_PDF.html and Item_PDF Hoverpanel.html files, but am apparently not getting through the if(!Srch.U.n(ctx.CurrentItem.ServerRedirectedEmbedURL)) condition...

Comment: on your item_pdf.html file, are you missing code from line 25-30 from the original file? See: http://ctrlv.in/845851
Please post your code (pastie.org works great)

Comment: Item_PDF did have these lines, and works as expected, along with Item_PDF_Hoverpanel (w/image display). The Item template I am using was provided by Scot Hillier as mentioned above, and was missing these lines, which I added, but still no image display in the stock PDF hoverpanel. And Pastie says service unavailable right now? I'll post my code above...

Comment: your hoverUrl points to OOTB hover js not your custom 'Item_SEDA_HoverPanel.js'. Remove all spaces from 'ManagedPropertyMapping' put all in a single line (not multi-line or spaced) Not sure what else is going on. I didn't know pastie.org went down , anyways Pastebin.com is an alternative. Also, strip out your domain name from your code. Good luck!

Comment: Added 'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL' to Managed Property Mappings on Item_SEDA template to resolve missing PDF image in Hoverpanel. Thx to wjervis. and Thx again @Aveenav!

Comment: glad you found the missing piece.